# Configure browserSync with nodejs server

Tags: node.js, gulp, browser-sync

I need help in understanding how to configure the ports for node server and browser-sync.

Within the serevr.js file, the http server is listening on port 3006;
    `server.listen(3006);`

I would like browsersync to open the browser and point the address to server port `3006`. This is the port the http server listening to. So the address would be `localhost:3006`

**gulpfile.js**

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {
browserSync.init({
    server: {
        baseDir: './dist/'
    },
    port: 3006
 });
});
```

1. In the mac terminal, I run`gulp`. This opens the browser to `localhost:3006`. Fine.
2. In another terminal window, I start the node server, `nodemon dist/serevr.js`

I'm unable to get them to be the same. Either the server will not start because something is already running on port 3006, (step 1), or, the following happens if I start the server first.

---

```
Local: http://localhost:3007
External: http://192.168.1.63:3007
```

---

How can I get them to work together?

**Solution found with help from answers below:**

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        port: 3007,
        proxy: {
            target: "localhost:3006",
            ws: true
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will essentially be two servers running. One that `nodemon` operates and one that `browser-sync` will be operating. Both servers cannot have the same ports.

You need to proxy the port you use for nodemon in the browser-sync configuration section of your gulp file. Thus, you need to have the node server up first before browser-sync can proxy it.

If you need to enable websockets, you can do so by setting `ws: true`.

This is how it would look like:

```
gulp.task('browserSync', function () {
    browserSync.init({
        port: 3007, // you can specify the port here
              // can't use the same port that nodemon uses.
        proxy: {
            target: 'localhost:3006', // original port
            ws: true // enables websockets
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah I see. How do I maintain the websocket connection? 
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3007/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=uqjjv3tQ0dlAAAG' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
(index):28 connected !!

Comment: This works, thanks for the heads up about proxying the server

gulp.task('serve', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        port: 3007,
        proxy: {
            target: "localhost:3006",
            ws: true
        }

    });
});

Comment: I was just going to mention that! Yes, `ws: true` is needed if your server makes use of WebSockets.

Comment: Your answer was still relevant to my original question so.. :)

Answer (score 0):

browserSync.init starts the server. 
You can't bind to one port twice. Use different ports if you need to run both of servers together.